# Getting height of a canvas create window object python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a program where almost everything is placed in a canvas using frames and something like this : `

```
canvas = Canvas(root,width = 800, height = 800) 
frame = Frame(root)
window = canvas.create_window(10, 10, anchor = "nw", window = frame)
```

And some widgets inside that frame. My question is, how can I get width and height of `canvas.create_window` when  print`(canvas.bbox(window)` returns `(10, 115, 11, 116)` and the coordinates where I put it are 10,115, despite the widgets where already in the frame? Thanks

Comment: You need to call `root.update_idletasks()` to give the Frame a chance to decide how big it needs to be to hold its contents.

Comment: Thanks. That works.